# encodeURIComponent() doesn't seem to encode '+' characters with dojo.xhrPost()

Tags: javascript, dojo, urlencode

I am trying to encode a URL which is being passed as a parameter in a POST request. The URL contains '+' characters and javascript's encodeURIComponent() doesn't seem to encode those. Any idea why this might be the case ?

Code:

```
var url = "http://........"
 url += "&url=" + encodeURIComponent(params.url);

 var deferred = dojo.xhrPost({
        url: url,
        headers: { "X-Requested-With": null },
        sync: true,
        load: function(responseObject, ioArgs) {
            console.info(".....................");
            params.onSuccess();
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error("Error uploading image" + error);
            params.onError();
        }
    });
```

Actual URL:

```
http://......../images/I/41zMWkv3+9L._CLa|500,500|41c4imMJhOL.jpg,31PAFct+UsL.jpg_.jpg
```

Encoded URL:

```
http://......../images/I/41zMWkv3+9L._CLa%7C500,500%7C41c4imMJhOL.jpg,31PAFct+UsL.jpg_.jpg
```

The '|' characters were being encoded, but not the '+'.

This is resulting in the URL to be decoded to the one below ('+' replaced by ' ') on the server side:

```
http://......../images/I/41zMWkv3 9L._CLa|500,500|41c4imMJhOL.jpg,31PAFct UsL.jpg_.jpg
```

I would appreciate any help with this.

Thanks

Comment: what you are seeing is the specified behavior of the method.

Comment: @dandavis - Can you please elaborate on that ? As per the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) encodeURIComponent() is supposed to encode the '+' characters. Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1):

Also I had this particular problem when I worked with the querystring using `encodeURIComponent` or `decodeURIComponent()` for this character `+` or inverse `' '`

I had to use the `replace(" ", "+");` .

I say that is normal because look on this site and also it use the replace [SITE](http://www.sislands.com/coin70/week6/encoder.htm)
This site suggests replacing + with  when decoding, because unescape doesn't

I try and `+` encode in `%2B` [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrk1989/QywHd/)

Or with `decodeURIComponent()` but you not want [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrk1989/QywHd/1/)

**You** can working the url inside the variable with `var url=document.location.search;` that contain only part after the `.html`

**REPEAT:**

```
search          Returns the query portion of a URL
```

**Example:**

```
http://localhost:8100/index2?json_data=demo_title%24+Demo+title+%23+proc1_script%24+
```

with `document.location.search` :

```
?json_data=demo_title%24+Demo+title+%23+proc1_script%24+
```

**After** the working with `replace` or other method you can change the url of site with

```
document.location.href="index2"+url;
```

The index2 you can change with `index.html` or `exercise.html` (you have to know)

**You can look for encoding in all characters** on this [site](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php)

UPDATE

You try with this code:

```
var url = "http://........"
 url += "&url=" + encodeURIComponent(params.url);
//There is a error because miss `?` then you replace `"?url="` else leave so

 var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
  var xhrArgs= {
        url: url,
        headers: { "X-Requested-With": null },
        sync: true,
        load: function(responseObject, ioArgs) {
            console.info(".....................");
            params.onSuccess();
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error("Error uploading image" + error);
            params.onError();
        }
    });
```

And what is `params` ????

Comment: Sorry, I lost you. http://jsfiddle.net/mrk1989/QywHd/ seems to be working fine with encodeURIComponent(); the '+' character is being encoded. But, why doesn't it work in my code ? Am i using it incorrectly ? Thanks.

Comment: @soontobeared with the console you look/watch the error? th you code seem is correct